# How to link Submit Button to Random Math Equation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I am trying to generate 3 random math equations. The math is basic arithmetic. I do not knwo how to link the Submit button to my function. Please help!

Code:

```
        var questionCorrect = 0;
        var questionAsked = 0;

        function basic()
        {
            function ask() 
                {
                    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
                    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
                    var op = ["*", "+", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
                    $("#basic").text("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
                }     

                for(questionAsked=0; questionAsked<=2; questionAsked++)
                {
                    if(ask())
                    {
                        questionCorrect++;
                    }
                }

                //alert( "You got "+questionCorrect+"/"+questionAsked+" correctly");    

        }
```

HTML:

```
    <span id="basic"></span>

     <form id="basicAsk" name=form1>

               Answer:<input type="text" name="txtRadius" size=10>
               <input type="button" value="Submit Answer" onclick=""> 

    </form>
```

Comment: why are you wrapping the function within a function?

Comment: Well, im kinda trying to

Comment: Sorry! I am wrapping a function inside a function because that way my equation works.

Comment: I just do not know how to link the submit button to the function.

Comment: onclick="basic()" should do the trick as long as you include the javascript in the markup somewhere. Ask() doesnt have to be a subfunction of basic, since the only thing done within the basic function is calling the ask function

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're not using a submit button, you're just using a regular button and writing logic forcing it to behave similar to a submit button.  A submit button is tied to the form and has `type="submit"`.  The `form` tag would include `onsubmit="basic()"` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To link the function `basic()` to your button use:

```
onclick="basic()"
```

But I don't understand what are you trying to do.

The `if(ask())` never will be `true` because the function returns no value.

Can you explain what you want? Because without this we can´t help you.

---

Try changing your function `ask` to

```
function ask() {
            var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            var op = [ "*", "+", "-" ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

            return eval(a + op + b) ==  prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?","");

        }
```

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="basic()"
```

Why are you wrapping the function within a function?

Comment: I tried doing that but the equation would not take the answer when submitted.

Comment: Are you trying to send something in to your function?

Comment: I see what youre trying to do. You want a javascriptfunction to generate a question for the user to reply on. The problem is that you dont generate the question ahead, so your logic doesnt make much sence like it is now